# Optimizing python DFS (for loop is inefficient)

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, optimization, depth-first-search

Given the following function, what would be the correct and pythonic way to archiving the same (and faster) result?

My code is not efficient and I believe I'm missing something that is staring at me.

The idea is to find a pattern that is [[A,B],[A,C],[C,B]] without having to generate additional permutations (since this will result in a higher processing time for the comparisons).

The length of the dictionary fed into `find_path` in real-life would be approximately 10,000, so having to iterate over that amount with the current code version below is not efficient.

```
from time import perf_counter
from typing import List, Generator, Dict


def find_path(data: Dict) -> Generator:
    for first_pair in data:

        pair1: List[str] = first_pair.split("/")

        for second_pair in data:
            pair2: List[str] = second_pair.split("/")
            if pair2[0] == pair1[0] and pair2[1] != pair1[1]:

                for third_pair in data:
                    pair3: List[str] = third_pair.split("/")

                    if pair3[0] == pair2[1] and pair3[1] == pair1[1]:

                        amount_pair_1: int = data.get(first_pair)[
                            "amount"
                        ]
                        id_pair_1: int = data.get(first_pair)["id"]

                        amount_pair_2: int = data.get(second_pair)[
                            "amount"
                        ]
                        id_pair_2: int = data.get(second_pair)["id"]

                        amount_pair_3: int = data.get(third_pair)[
                            "amount"
                        ]
                        id_pair_3: int = data.get(third_pair)["id"]

                        yield (
                            pair1,
                            amount_pair_1,
                            id_pair_1,
                            pair2,
                            amount_pair_2,
                            id_pair_2,
                            pair3,
                            amount_pair_3,
                            id_pair_3,
                        )


raw_data = {
    "EZ/TC": {"id": 1, "amount": 9},
    "LM/TH": {"id": 2, "amount": 8},
    "CD/EH": {"id": 3, "amount": 7},
    "EH/TC": {"id": 4, "amount": 6},
    "LM/TC": {"id": 5, "amount": 5},
    "CD/TC": {"id": 6, "amount": 4},
    "BT/TH": {"id": 7, "amount": 3},
    "BT/TX": {"id": 8, "amount": 2},
    "TX/TH": {"id": 9, "amount": 1},
}


processed_data = list(find_path(raw_data))

for i in processed_data:
    print(("The path to traverse is:", i))

>> ('The path to traverse is:', (['CD', 'TC'], 4, 6, ['CD', 'EH'], 7, 3, ['EH', 'TC'], 6, 4))
>> ('The path to traverse is:', (['BT', 'TH'], 3, 7, ['BT', 'TX'], 2, 8, ['TX', 'TH'], 1, 9))
>> ('Time to complete', 5.748599869548343e-05)

# Timing for a simple ref., as mentioned above, the raw_data is a dict containing about 10,000 keys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with this representation of the graph. This algorithm has `O(|E|^3)` time complexity. It is a good idea to store edges as array of lists, each list will store only adjacent vertexes. And then it is easy to do what you need. Fortunately, you can re-represent graph in `O(|E|)` time.

### How to do that

We will store graph as **array of vertices** (but in this case because of *string* vertex-values we take a *dictionary*). We want to access in all neighbours by a vertex. Let's do that -- we will store in the array **lists of all neighbours** of the given vertex.

Now we just need to construct our structure by set of edges (aka *row_data*).
How to add an edge in graph? Easy! We should find a vertex **from** in our *array* and add a vertex **to** to the list of it's neighbours

So, the **construct_graph** function could be like:

```py
def construct_graph(raw_data):  # here we will change representation
    graph = defaultdict(list)   # our graph
    for pair in raw_data:       # go through every edge
        u, v = pair.split("/")  # get from and to vertexes
        graph[u].append(v)      # and add this edge in our structure
    return graph                # return our new graph to other functions
```

### How to find path length 2

We will use `dfs` on our graph.

```py
def dfs(g, u, dist):                # this is a simple dfs function
    if dist == 2:                   # we has a 'dist' from our start
        return [u]                  # and if we found already answer, return it
    for v in g.get(u, []):          # otherwise check all neighbours of current vertex
        ans = dfs(g, v, dist + 1)   # run dfs in every neighbour with dist+1
        if ans:                     # and if that dfs found something
            ans.append(u)           # store it in ouy answer
            return ans              # and return it
    return []                       # otherwise we found nothing
```

And then we just try it for every vertex.

```py
def main():
    graph = construct_graph(raw_data)
    for v in graph.keys():              # here we will try to find path
        ans = dfs(graph, v, 0)          # starting with 0 dist
        if ans:                         # and if we found something
            print(list(reversed(ans)))  # return it, but answer will be reversed
```

Comment: do you have an idea on how to do that in code? Thank you for the reply and explanation, could you elaborate a bit more or give an example?

Comment: @Corfucinas I did it

Comment: Amazing, that works!
 
Just to give you an idea in regards of time (ran 1,000,000 times):

old version
Python: 35.78 s
Pypy 8.61 s

Your version
Python 7.5 s
Pypy 1.8 s